# How to rewrite the htaccess conditions in my case

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rewrite statement in my .htaccess like below. 
Is it possible to make it less line or fewer statement?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file1.asp
RewriteRule ^.*$ /project/test.php?file=1 [R=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /customer.form
RewriteRule ^.*$ /project/test.php?form=true [R=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /clear
RewriteRule ^.*$ /project/test.php?clear=1 [R=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /redirect
RewriteRule ^.*$ /project/test.php?url=play [R=302
```

]

I feel like the above statement could be reduce. Is it possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a single rule like this using regex alternation:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (file1\.asp|customer\.form|clear|redirect) /project/test.php [R=302,L,NC]
```

This replaces all of your 4 rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava Please see my updated question. How do I pass the query string based on the url to test.php in my case? +1

Comment: Please don't do this. You recent edit has totally changed the nature of the question. Now single rule won't work, just `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` can be removed.

Comment: my bad. so I assume there is not much we can do here?

Comment: Only `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` can be removed for each rule as I showed above.